# Mac App Store reasons for SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed with unknown error?

Tags: in-app-purchase, mac-app-store

I have a Mac OSX app in production, available for download via the Mac App Store. The app uses in-app-purchase to buy a single non-consumable item (unlocking the Pro version of the app). The purchase mechanism works fine on all my machines (both in testing and also production, I've even spent my own money testing the app on the store!) Many customers successfully purchase the Pro version.

However, several customers have also reported problems when trying to purchase, and looking at the available anonymous usage data suggest a significant percentage of customers may be having trouble. In almost all cases, it seems that

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

is called with `transaction.transactionState` being set to `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` with the corresponding `transaction.error` set to `Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown Error." NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.`

How should one go about debugging this? What are the cases that can lead to this error? It would be great to have a list so that one would know what could be done.

For example, on my machine, trying to buy and then, when prompted for the Apple ID password, if one clicks Cancel this leads to the above error. What are some other reasons? (Since several users have reported problems, and presumably they have not simply decided to cancel their purchase...)

UPDATE: Using the software 'Little Snitch 3' I observed that my app (production app installed from the Mac App Store) contacted the server sandbox.itunes.apple.com (via storeinappd or something similar), in addition to a bunch of other apple servers. Should a production app ever attempt to connect to the sandbox? Is this an indication that something is wrong?

Thanks for any help! I'm new here, but I'll try to be responsive in providing more info (if needed) and responding to comments and answers!

Comment: Just added an extra fact: Using a network monitor it seems that the app did contact the sandbox (in addition to a bunch of other apple servers), even though it is a production version. Is this normal?